# Creating a Column that is a sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

Animals:

```
id:1, name:"Bears" , otherFields... 
id:2, name:"Hamster", otherFields...
id:3, name:"Panda", otherFields...
```

Food:

```
name: "fish" animalId:1, otherFields...
name: "birds" animalId:1, otherFields...
name: "seeds", animalId:2, otherFields...
name: "bamboo", animalId:3, otherFields...
```

I want to create a table that creates a new column called total_food that is the sum of a food each animal can eat from the Food table.

eg.

Result:

```
id:1, name:"Bears", total_food: 2 
id:2, name:"Hamster", total_food: 1 
id:3, name:"Panda", total_food: 1
```

How would I join the 2 tables?

SQL:

To get animalFoodCount:

```
SELECT animalId, count(*)
FROM Food
GROUP BY animalId;

SELECT id, name
From Animals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

One approach is to use a `left join` to capture all animals even if there are no food's which they eat (the unlikely possibility)

```sql
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name,
    COUNT(F.animalId) as total_food
FROM
    Animals A
LEFT JOIN
    Food F ON A.id = F.animalId
GROUP BY
    A.id, A.name
```

### Sample Run

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table animals(id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(40));
create table foods(id int auto_increment primary key, animalId int);
                                                        
insert into animals(name) values('cat'),('dog'),('cow');
                                                        
insert into foods(animalId) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name,
   COUNT(F.animalId) as total_food
FROM
    animals A
LEFT JOIN
    foods F ON A.id = F.animalId
GROUP BY
   A.id, A.name;
```

---

```
| id  | name | total_food |
| --- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1   | cat  | 3          |
| 2   | dog  | 2          |
| 3   | cow  | 0          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fPPHRbRNvTrCDGbmfdRm84/1)